# Library not found for -lGTMSessionFetcher

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

Unity 5.6.2, Firebase Unity SDK 4.0.3, Cocoapod 1.3.1 I added Firebase Auth package to Unity Project and Android works fine. But when I run the same project on iOs, build in Unity runs fine, but fails in XCode during compilation

```
ld: library not found for -lGTMSessionFetcher clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

I've tried to add Firebase Auth form Unity SDK 4.1.0, but Unity started to fail due to:

```
iOS framework addition failed due to a Cocoapods installation failure.
Specs satisfying the 'Firebase/DynamicLinks (=4.0.4)' dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target
```

pod spec cat DynamicLinks output

```
"platforms": {
   "ios": "7.0"
}
```

and I have 9.0 in my Unity project

Answer (score 3):

This error happens when you open `.xcodeproj` instead of `.xcworkspace`.

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/539)