# command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 while archiving the code Swift IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I recently purchased a developer account, and wanted to Test Flight my app. But when i went to archive my app, i faced an error Command /bin/sh failed with an exit code 1.

I think it has something to do with GTMSessionFetcher.

The error is attached below .

Please help me .
Thanks

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Looks like you're using a framework that has problem with archive. Do you know what is GTMSessionFetcher?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858482/library-not-found-for-lgtmsessionfetcher. The reference has a bounty