# Build game from unity to iphone (library not found for -lGTMSessionFetcher)?

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a mobile game for IOS with unity and opened the `.xcodeproj` file with xcode. Next I want to get this game working on my iPhone.

I found this video helpful:
[How to Build a Unity Game to iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80-nE7ichvk)

But still receive two errors:

1. Your development team, "myname", does not support the In-App Purchase capability.
2. No profiles for 'com.myname.gamename' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.myname.gamename'.

I cannot find the solution online and leaving the bundle identifier black does not work either. The bundle ids are the same in unity and xcode.

EDIT: I disabled the in-app-purchase capability and that solved these errors.

I still have this one:

```
library not found for -lGTMSessionFetcher
```

[image]

I never used this library in my code, so it must come from unity or xcode. How can I include the library in my project at this point?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that also solved my problem. [Library not found for -lGTMSessionFetcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858482/library-not-found-for-lgtmsessionfetcher)

Basically you must not open the `.xcodeproj` file but the `.xcworkspace` file instead